# How can we know if we can install a plugin on both Vim and Neovim?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, gvim, plugin, plugin-vim-plug

I find in [neovimcraft](https://neovimcraft.com/) a list of Neovim plugins

Can we install them inside Vim or gVim?

It seems that the plugins in [vimawsome](https://vimawesome.com/) can be installed on Neovim but not always in Vim.

Is that correct?

How can we determine if we can install a plugin on both Neovim and Vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most plugins are compatible for both Vim and Neovim.

I'm not aware of any popular plugins that is Vim compatible and not Neovim compatible.

Neovim has a more rich Lua binding and some plugins make use of that functionality making them not compatible with Vim.

You'll find on the home page of the plugin the requirements for Neovim only.

Some examples are:

- [Telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim)
- [nvim-Tree](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua)
- [GitSigns](https://github.com/lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim)
- [nvim-TreeSitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter)
- [nvim-Cmp](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp)
- [Packer](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim)
- [Dashboard](https://github.com/glepnir/dashboard-nvim)
- [Leap](https://github.com/ggandor/leap.nvim)
- [Hop](https://github.com/phaazon/hop.nvim)
- ...

The Neovim tag on [VimAwesome](https://vimawesome.com) gives you a hint that the plugin is for Neovim only (VimAwesome contains both Vim and Neovim only plugins).

[image]

The [NeovimCraft](https://neovimcraft.com) seems to focus on Neovim only plugins but some plugins of the list are also compatible with Vim (e.g. [barbar](https://github.com/romgrk/barbar.nvim) or [markdowns-preview](https://github.com/iamcco/markdown-preview.nvim))

Comment: Thanks, do you use neovim personally?

Comment: You are welcome. I'm using both but spending more time in gVim.

Comment: vimspector at least used to work much better on vim.

Comment: @eyal can you give me an exemple I'm interested to document it.

Comment: https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector see neovim differences. No balloons for example.